# understanding Rails initialization when we execute rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to know what command I am executing. The rails initializers are executed for most of the commands like rake `db:migrate, rake db:setup, rails console, rails server`.

The reason for this question is that I start scheduling some jobs using Rufus-scheduler during rails initialization. Unfortunately all these initializers are getting executed while executing `rails console` or rake `db:migrate` also. I want to schedule jobs only when I execute `rails server`.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to schedule jobs only when I am running the server, the following command helps to understand that we are running server.

```
defined?(Rails::Server)
```

This solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The rake tasks you are mentioning, and most Rails-related tasks, depend upon the `environment` rake task. This rake task loads `config/environment.rb` which requires `config/application.rb` which in turn requires each of the files and dependencies needed for your application, including the initializers under `config/initializers/`.

If you have things that shouldn't be included in this dependency graph, they probably don't belong in initializers.

A common way to have 'background workers' is to have a separate rake task and use a library such as [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman), which will read a `Procfile` to start up multiple processes.

An example:

```
app: rails server
workers: rake jobs:work
```

Comment: I also have a requirement of managing those scheduled jobs through Rails UI, if I start with Foreman, I will not be able to control the other proces, I mean reschedule the jobs.

Comment: That isn't really something Rails is very good at. I'd recommend using heroku's scheduler if you need something like that.

Comment: At any rate, your Rails UI can set a timestamp, let's call it next_run_at, and your worker can know to check for that and not do anything until it comes up on that time.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. We are deploying our app on AWS and not on Heroku. ClockWork seems a nice solution, but again we need to read records from database and schedule when Rails is started. Most likely we are going to schedule it manually by clicking a button for the first time.

Comment: Did my answer satisfy your actual question? It seems like you were trying to understand how the rake tasks work more than asking about your scheduling specifically.

Comment: Not actually Caleb. It looks like there is no clear to answer to the question I asked. So for now, we schedule the jobs by clicking the button manually. I perhaps realize that Rails may not handle my requirements better.